# Android button to show and hide the same popup

Tags: android, android-layout

Could anyone please tell me that how is it possible to show and hide the same popup window using a single button.

suggestions welcome.

---

Popup means that when i clicked on a menu button it showing a popup window which contains the listview and when i clicked on the menu button again and touches anywhere on the screen,the popwindow should disappear.

Comment: what do you mean by popup? is ita dialog that you are launching or a new view simulating popup?

Comment: use a boolean field as a flag. however, consider the possibility that your button may be covered by your popup

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use the bellow code to do that. In your case the `menuButton` is your single button and `content` is your listview. The `anchor` can be the `menuButton` itself or another `View`.

```
public static void setupMenuButton(View menuButton, View content, final View anchor) {
    PopupWindow popup;

    menuButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (popup == null) {
            popup = new PopupWindow(content, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        }

        if (popup.isShowing()) popup.dismiss();
        else popup.showAsDropDown(anchor);
    });
}
```